# Can someone go around the .htaccess file without modifying it?

Tags: security, apache-2.4, .htaccess

I'm storing some sensitive data in a folder called `/data/`. This folder contains some files, and a subdirectory.

The subdirectory contains a modified version of the sensitive data, with the same filename.

Therefore, i have `/data/file.exe` and `/data/modified/file.exe`. I have set some rules in `.htaccess` file to block any access from outside the server to the `/data/` folder, but not to the `/data/modified/`.

Since the filenames are the same, anyone that has access to the `/data/modified/` folder know that the original file exists in `/data/` with the same name.

Now the question is, Is this safe? Can anyone overwrite these rules and have access to these files without breaking into server or modifying the `.htaccess` file? I know that you can do anything once you have access to the server.

I'm using Apache web server V.2.4 on windows server 2008, but might move to LiteSpeed on CentOS.

**PS:** Please tell me if this is the wrong place/format to ask this question, so i can move, edit or remove it. Thanks.

Comment: Specifically what directives are you using to protect this directory? Presumably, since `/data` is protected, `/data/modified` is also protected?

Comment: @w3dk Hi, i mentioned that i don't block access to the `/data/modified/` folder. I'm using a simple `deny from all` in the `/data/` and opposite rule in the `/modified/` folder.

Comment: There shouldn't be an easy way for a hacker to simply circumvent `.htaccess`. The most probable way-in would be exploiting a vulnerability in any outdated software, eg. WordPress, etc.?

Comment: That's what i thought. I wanted to use WordPress's rewrite function to limit the access, but since WordPress is being hacked each day, i decided to do it using `.htaccess` and make the file read only for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an ideal setup because your public folder is a sub-folder of your protected directory. So everyone who browses /data/modified knows that the parent folder is forbidden. It is a matter of time before someone tries to check if a /data/modified/file.exe is also contained in the /data/file.exe and he will get a hit.

My suggestion is to separate your folder structure as: 
/data_modified 
/data_secure (you might want to be more inventive with this folder name).

Now nobody knows the secure folder new name hence they do not know where to look for your sensitive data as you are not giving away the folder name anymore.

Other than that if you are using .htaccess to forbid access to the directory it stands good from a security point of view and access to your data should not be possible without unauthorized access to the server. 
But if you are using it to provide access by username/password you should be extremely careful. If you are not using HTTPS most probably the username/password pair is negotiated in plain text over your network.

You might also want to have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441578/how-secure-is-htaccess-password-protection) on how to secure .htaccess if you are offering user/pass access.

Comment: Since `/data_secure` is protected by a `deny from all` then maybe this directory should be above the document root?

Comment: Thank you for the answer louis. I forgot to mention that i can't change the directory structures (software limitation) and i'm not giving user/pass to anyone. And yes, people know the secure version is stored in `/data/`. I just wanted to know if they can access it or not?